# MVC Email Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formatting

Here are my two actions for sending emails via MVC:

```
[HttpGet]
    // GET: EmailForms
    public ActionResult EmailForm(int id)
    {
        EmailFormModel emailModel = new EmailFormModel();
        ChosenWT cwt = new ChosenWT();
        OInfo person= new OInfo();
        using (var db = new OWTEntities())
        {
            cwt = db.ChosenWTs.Find(id);
            person= db.OInfoes.Find(cwt.OID);
        }
        emailModel.Message = "This is paragraph 1.\n\nThis is paragraph 2.\n\nThis is paragraph 3." // issue deals with this property

        emailModel.FromEmail = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1] + "@domain.com";
        string Logon = Common.GetLogon(person.IBM);
        emailModel.ToEmail = Logon + "@domain.com";
        return View(emailModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> EmailForm(EmailFormModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Message:</p><p>{2}</p>";
            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(model.ToEmail));
            message.From = new MailAddress(model.FromEmail);
            message.Subject = "Test Program";
            message.Body = string.Format(body, model.FromName, model.FromEmail, model.Message); // This doesn't keep the paragraph formatting like in the [HttpGet] Action.. Instead it just combines it all into 1 big paragraph..

            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                smtp.Host = "smtp.test.server";
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "OInfoes");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

If you read the comments I put in the code above, that is the issue with this code.

I can format the `Message` so that when the user first comes to the page, the string is formatted into paragraph form.. but when I click Send, the `HttpPost` Action takes the message and ignores the `\n\n` and combines it all into one giant paragraph.

So I have tried to include `<p></p>` symbols into the string, but when I hit submit, I get an error stating that those characters are potentially dangerous.

Is there a way for the formatting to stay the same when i submit?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the exact error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting the error is, when a form is submitted, the asp.met mvc framework will inspect the request body to see whether it has any potentially dangerous content as HTML markup(***Think about script injection***). If it detects any dangerous content,the Request Validation module will throw an error. This is by design

You can apply `AllowHtml` attribute to the property which holds the html markup in your view model class so that the request validation framework won't reject the data submitted.

```
public class EmailFormModel
{      
  [AllowHtml]
  public string Message { set;get;}

  public string FromEmail {set;get;}

  //Other properties of view model goes here

}
```

Comment: Ahh that worked. I knew what the error meant.. I didn't mean for that part of the question to be the focus.. I just wanted to know if there was a way to keep the formatting.

Comment: If you have `IsBodyHtml` set to true and provide html mark (ex : `<p>` tags). It should work.